# Why pymongo throwing Attribute-error: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'find' on second time execution

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In pymongo, first time when I am executing i am getting the proper out. Second I am getting AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'find'

```
courses = courses.find()
for course in courses:
    pprint.pprint(course)
```

Full code is below, don't forget the install and start mongod server

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
db  = client['test-database']
##New collection #courses = db['course']
courses = db.courses
print (courses)
#insert new document# create a new dict
course = {
    'author':'Mak',
    'course':'Data',
    'price': 100,
    'rating':5
    }
#insert
result = courses.insert_one(course)
#check whether doc is inserted
if result.acknowledged:
    print ("course added course id is", str(result.inserted_id))
#how to insert many doc
arr_courses =  [ {
    'author':'Hus',
    'course':'Data',
    'price': 100,
    'rating':5},
{
    'author':'ais',
    'course':'Data',
    'price': 100,
    'rating':3.5}
]

result = courses.insert_many(arr_courses)
for object_id in result.inserted_ids:
    print ("course added course id is", object_id)
courses.find_one()
print (course)
courses = courses.find()
for course in courses:
    pprint.pprint(course)
```

My Question how to use `courses = courses.find()` again and again for processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the variable `courses` too many times and got confused there.

At line 9, `courses` is a `Collection`. You can check this by modifying the line slightly to:

```
print ('Courses 1:', courses)
```

It will print:

```
Courses 1: Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True), 'test-database'), 'courses')
```

Now add a similar print statement after the last line in your example above, e.g.:

```
print ('Courses 2:', courses)
```

It will now print:

```
Courses 2: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x10d284ef0>
```

This is what the error `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'find'` is talking about. You are trying to call `find()` on a `Cursor` object.

Comment: Ok, that is why only one time its executing. is there any way to use ***courses = courses.find()*** again and again for processing like aggregate, sort?

Comment: Don't redefine `courses` and don't do something like `courses = courses.find()`. You are changing what `courses` is and got confused as a result.